# react-toolbox installation on a react-native app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-toolbox

When I use the install commando ( npm install --save react-toolbox) on a react native app, I get the following errors:

```
── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY normalize.css@^4.0.0
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-addons-css-transition-group@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1
└─┬ react-toolbox@1.0.1 
  ├── classnames@2.2.5 
  ├── core-js@2.4.0 
  └── react-css-themr@1.1.3
```

Is it possible to install the toolbox on a react-native app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, React toolbox is not supporting React Native.

> javivelasco (React toolbox contributor) : That would be awesome but for now I think it's quite difficult to port
>   all of this to React Native. Since we are using CSS modules we are
>   also using features that cannot be directly ported to native
>   components. For the javascript maybe we can create factories to inject
>   native or web elements but the styling approach is way more difficult.
>   So for now we are going to make styles fully responsive so we can
>   mobile friendly web apps and let's see in the future what can be
>   figure out with native!

Souce : https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/issues/40